# Unable to Apply Dark Mode Theme in Material-UI (MUI) React App

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, web-development-server

I'm working on a React app using Material-UI (MUI), and I'm trying to implement a dark mode functionality. However, the theme is not changing when I toggle the dark mode switch.
code snippets required:

Expected Behavior:expect the app to switch between light and dark themes when the toggle switch is clicked.

Actual Behavior: Describe the behavior you are observing currently when you toggle the switch. Is the theme not changing? Is the entire app becoming blank white?

to Reproduce:
Clone the repository from https://github.com/Codesaur1618/todolist.